# How can I find the longest word in a string?

Tags: python

Problem: I want the user to input a sentence (string) and use a loop to check which is the longest word to return.

My solution:

```
string = input("Please enter a string ")
new = string.split()
max_length = 0
max_word = ""

for word in new:
    if len(word) > max_length:
        max_length = len(word)
        max_word = word

print("The longest word in the string is", max_word)
```

Question: How can I get printed *only* the largest word?

Comment: What's the error? Do you have a trace, or is it giving an unexpected output? If you could provide the input, expected output and/or trace, then that would help us a lot :)

Comment: Fixing the indentation worked for me.

Comment: when I run this code I get all words as the longest...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the longest word with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192881/how-to-find-the-longest-word-with-python)

Comment: Given this indentation, I don't see how it could print every word as the longest.  There is only one print statement, and it is not in a loop.

Comment: Example of running this code: Please enter a string: the banana
The longest word in the string is:  the
The longest word in the string is:  banana

Comment: If it's printing `The longest word in the string is ...` more than once, then that print statement must be inside the loop, but that is not what the question shows.  Please update the posted code to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max` on the splitted string with `key` as `len`:

```
max_word = max(string.split(), key=len)
```

You can also correct your code to:

```
string = input("Please enter a string ")

max_word = ''
for word in string.split():
    if len(word) > len(max_word):
        max_word = word

print(max_word)
```

Comment: Thanks! this optional code which is simpler solved the issue :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `max` function and supply `len` as the key:

```
max_word = max(string.split(), key=len)
print("The longest word in the string is ", max_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to take the string with `input()`:

```
print('The longest word is: ', max(input('Please enter a string: ').split(), key=len))
```

Or you can make it a function:

```
func = lambda x:max(x.split(), key=len)
```

and use the function like this:

```
the_longest_word = func('here is some string')
```